# Setting PATH environment variable on ant build.xml works on cygwin but not on cmd or PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ant, cygwin, cmd, environment-variables

I was trying to set PATH enviroment variable on an ant build.xml through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5607580/174605).

It works on cygwin but not on cmd or PowerShell.

Some information:

Apache Ant 1.6.5 (I know there is a newer version (1.8.4), but for internal reasons I have to use this older version)

Powershell v2.0

cmd v6.1.7601

cygwin 2.774

Windows 7

Comment: are you trying to use the `exec` task?

Comment: Yep, the same as at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/5607580/174605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly was an ant bug related to 1.6.5 version. I was able to update to 1.8.4 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to use the `exec` task a little differently on Windows/cmd environments.

Let's use the windows command `set` as an example. `set` will print environment variables. A normal `exec` task running a `set` command might look like:

```
<exec executable="set" outputproperty="set.output">
    <env key="MY_VAR" value="MY_VAL"/>
    <echo message="${set.output}"/>
</exec>
```

But using this form of the `exec` task should throw an IOException: *The system cannont find the file specified*.

When running ant under windows cmd shell, the `exec` task can also be invoked via `cmd`, like this:

```
<exec executable="cmd" outputproperty="set.output">
    <arg line="/c set"/>
    <env key="MY_VAR" value="MY_VAL"/>
    <echo message="${set.output}"/>
</exec>
```

This is the equivalent command; the actual command executed is `cmd /c set`, which is running `set` in a cmd sub-process.

The reason why this is necessary is only a little complicated and is due to the way that the commands are located by Win32 `::CreateProcess`. The [ant exec docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) briefly explain this.

**Note** that I haven't tried either of these using PowerShell, so I have no experience which, if either, will work.

In my own ant build scripts I typically have two versions of each target that require special handling for windows platforms, with an `isWindows` test that looks like this:

```
<target name="check-windows">
    <condition property="isWindows">
        <os family="windows"/>
    </condition>
</target>
```

Then I can switch between versions of the same task using:

```
<target name="my-target-notwindows" depends="check-windows" unless="isWindows>
    ...
</target>

<target name="my-target-windows" depends="check-windows" if="isWindows>
    ...
</target>

<target name="my-target" depends="my-target-notwindows,my-target-windows">
    ...
</target>
```