# How to change the Path variable in ant exec task?

Tags: ant, exec, environment-variables, setx

I tried setting the `Path` variable `in ant exec` task using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607580/how-to-set-the-path-environment-variable-from-ant-script) link. But its not working somehow. I am trying to add `THRIFT_HOME` which is `set to basedir` currently and I have the `thrift.exe` file in the `basedir`.

Also, when I change `executable attribute value` to `thrift.exe`, the thrift compiler works properly but the `basedir` is `not added` to the `Path`.

```
<exec executable="thrift">
    <env key="Path" value="${env.Path};${THRIFT_HOME}" />
</exec>
```

I also tried using the `setx` command as:

```
<exec executable="setx">
    <arg value="Path"/>
    <arg value="%Path%;${THRIFT_HOME}"/>
</exec>
```

but it still does not work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: ant seems to sometimes "unify" environment variables i.e. by making it all uppercase ... have you tried to set `key="PATH"` instead of `key="Path"` ?

Comment: Yes already tried that..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the path environment variable from ant script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607580/how-to-set-the-path-environment-variable-from-ant-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently using on Windows 7 and the problem was with spaces in the folder name. That's a big problem when working on Windows.

I tried placing the thrift executable at `/d/thrift/` and it worked and assigning `THRIFT_HOME = /d/thrift`. Then  I tried `/d/thrift demo/` and there is the problem.

```
D:\noknok_fido_to_ostp\noknok_fido_to_ostp_workspace\Demo\build.xml:33: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "thrift-0.9.0.exe": CreateProces
s error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
        ... 23 more
```

Another problem is that `/d/thrift` doesn't work in `Eclipse Ant plugin build`. I tried it using command prompt and the build was successful.

This teaches a new lesson: **Always build from command prompt!**

Thanks to all who answered for this question.

Comment: Why downvote?? I don't need the bounty!! Its just that I accepted the answer to avoid further answers!!

Comment: I downvoted because it is not an answer to the question (note that I upvoted the question since I think it is interesting)

Comment: OK... did you try to escape the white space ? (with a backslash) and is working or not ?

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<!-- to see if you can access it -->
<echo message="${env.Path}" />
<exec executable="thrift">
    <env key="Path" value="${env.Path};${THRIFT_HOME}" />
</exec>
```

I've found a hint here: http://www.factsandpeople.com/facts-mainmenu-5/23-other-software-technologies/125-using-environment-variables-in-ant-environment-variables-are-not-evaluated

Answer (score 0):

And what about [`searchpath`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) attribute ?

> searchpath:   When this attribute is true, then system path environment variables will be searched when resolving the location of the executable. since Ant 1.6.3

So I think something like this:

```
    <exec executable="thrift" searchpath="true">
       <env key="Path" value="${env.Path};${THRIFT_HOME}" />
    </exec>
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Good to know about searchpath but the actual answer is below.

Comment: hum... your accepted answer is probably the solution to your problem, but in any case an answer to your own question.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for that.. Windows 7 should have been in problem requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I found it works by quote the value of variable

`<exec executable="setx">
    <arg line="Path &quot;${env.Path};c:\test Path&quot;" />
    <arg line="/m" />
</exec>`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23777929/3659861