# setting env variable with ant's exec task - doesn't seem to work

Tags: ant, environment-variables

When I try to set some varible with ant's exec task, it doesn't seem to set to my required value. Not sure what's wrong here.

It works perfectly file when I set & echo from command line with cmd.

```
<exec executable="cmd">
    <arg value="set"/>
    <arg value="MY_VAR=SOME_VAL"/>
</exec>
```

-->

```
<echo message="MY_VAR is set to %MY_VAR%"/>
```

And output looks like:

```
exec
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\MY_PROJ_BASE_DIR_HERE>
echo
MY_VAR is set to **%MY_VAR%**
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607580/how-to-set-the-path-environment-variable-from-ant-script

Comment: I tried with

 <property environment="env"/>
        <exec executable="cmd">
            <env key="MY_VAR" value="SOME_VAL"/>
        </exec>

it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `/C` option of `cmd.exe`.

### build.xml

```
<project name="ant-exec-cmd-with-env-key" default="run">
    <target name="run">
        <exec executable="cmd" failonerror="true">
            <env key="MY_VAR" value="SOME_VAL"/>
            <arg value="/c"/>
            <arg value="echo %MY_VAR%"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

### Output

```
run:
     [exec] SOME_VAL
```

Comment: Accepted your answer. Small query, for accessing %MY_VAR% outside of exec, I need to again use property ant task?.

Comment: copying into new property won't work! :(

exec doesn't support the nested "property" element.

Comment: As I've posted it, MY_VAR only exists for the lifetime of the `<exec>` task. If you need some kind of property to reference after the task completes, set a property before the call to `<exec>` and pass that reference to `<exec>`: `<property name="my.var.local" value="SOME_VAL"/> <exec...><env key="MY_VAR" value="${my.var.local}"/>...</exec>`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the problem is not in your reading of the variable?

```
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="MY_VAR" value="${env.MY_VAR}"/>
```

Comment: We cannot use property inside exec.

'exec doesn't support the nested "property" element.' . I am trying to set some variable with 'set MY_VAR=SOME_VAL' on windows & similar way want to use export on *nix