# How to change system env with ant

Tags: java, ant

I want in my ant target set value of enviroment with name  "project_env", but I cant understand how... I tried this:

```
 <exec executable="export" >
  <env key="PROJECT_ENV" value="prod"/>
</exec>
```

but I see only error

```
Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "export": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The export command is a shell command, specific to certain command shells, not a separate executable. That's why you're getting that error.

You could wrap the execution of your ant script in a shell script. The shell script would set any prerequisite environment variables, then call ant. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PROJECT_ENV=prod
ant -f build.xml
```

Comment: You might also want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607580/how-to-set-the-path-environment-variable-from-ant-script

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve specfic `export` var on unix or its `set` counterpart on windows. This is just ant's style & allows you to have exports of variables within/specific to targets

```
<exec executable="sh">
   <arg value="export PROJECT_ENV=prod"/>
</exec>
```